# Change the import path of rcc module from Qt Designer

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyuic, pyrcc

I'm looking for a way to change the import path of the rcc module in the pyuic generated python file.

An example pyuic generated python code from a ui file:

```py
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
    
    class Ui_MainWindow(object):
        def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
            MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
            MainWindow.resize(249, 103)
            self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
            self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
            self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
            self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
            self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
            self.pushButton.setText("")
            icon = QtGui.QIcon()
            icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/gui_icons/res/play.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
            self.pushButton.setIcon(icon)
            self.pushButton.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(32, 32))
            self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
            self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
            MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    
            self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
            QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
    
        def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    import icons_mw_rc
```

I want to change `icons_mw_rc` import path to another location to better organize my source files [Example: `import qrc_res.icons_mw_rc`]. Is there a way to do that using Qt Designer without manually modifying the pyuic generated src file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [pyuic tool](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html#pyuic5) has some options for adjusting the resource import statement. You can achieve the equivalent of your example using the `--import-from` option:

```
pyuic5 --import-from=qrc_res -o mw.py mw.ui
```

which would add the following line to the generated python module:

```
from qrc_res import icons_mw_rc
```